# Jquery асинхронный цикл

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(init);   

function init() {
  $('#site-panel').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('#forum-panel').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('#tab1').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('#tab2').toggleClass('is-active').delay(5000);
}
</script>
```

Требуется, чтобы функция работала бесконечно с некоторой задержкой и не мешала загрузке страницы.

Comment: должно помочь использование `setInterval`: var timerId = setInterval(func / code, delay[, arg1, arg2...])

Comment: @lexxl , спасибо большое! Работает)

Comment: я оформил ответом, отметьте его принятым нажатием на галочку, если вам подходит моё решение

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `setInterval`:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  alert( "тик" );
}, 2000);
```

Для более гибкого управления запуском события можно рекурсивно использовать `setTimeout`:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  alert( "тик" );
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Для отмены циклического выполнения используйте `clearTimeout`:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timerId);
```